# Change Color of Inline Code in R Markdown Beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

I have reproduced a simple example of an R Markdown presentation (PDF). I am trying to figure out the best way to change the color of inline code. Specifically, the first line is just for reference (format), the second line with `\color` gives the output I want to achieve, however its specification seems a bit cumbersome to me, and the third line (which would be my preferred specification) with `\textcolor` unfortunately gives the wrong formatting.

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation
---

---

- `code` and no color
- \color{red} `code` \color{black} and color
- \textcolor{red}{`code`} and wrong format
```

The current output is as follows:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use markdown syntax like ` ... ` in the argument of a latex macro. However you can simplify the syntax of your second item by placing the colour change inside a group, this avoids the need to switch back to the normal font colour, which might not always be black

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
---

---

- `code`, and no color
- \begingroup\color{red}`code`\endgroup, and color
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to do what I was looking for. The only drawback I have observed so far is that this procedure introduces a space between the inline code e.g., a comma if there is a comma after the inline code, which should be in the default color. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: @carl See my edit